# Creating Relationship on the fly for Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm quite new in `Neo4j` and I am very excited to learn.
Currently I am using a movie database and trying to solve an issue where I need to create relationship between actor based on what movie they acts on together.

For example, *Harrison Ford* and *Alec Guiness* acts on the same 4 movies. *Harisson Ford* total movie is 34 movies and *Alec Guiness* total movie is 16 movies.

I would like to create relationship on the fly to say:

```
"Harrison Ford"-[:SAME_MOVIE{weight: 0.12 }]->"Alec Guiness"

"Alec Guiness"-[:SAME_MOVIE{weight: 0.25 }]->"Harrison Ford"
```

I am stuck at getting this calculation and alias, would really appreciate if anyone can help.

```
MATCH (a:Actor{name:"Alec Guinness"})-[x:ACTS_IN]->(:Movie)<-[y:ACTS_IN]-(b:Actor{name:"Harrison Ford"})
RETURN {start: a.name, rel: count(x), end : b.name}
```

PS: Creating a relationship physically is not an option as in a real case it will take a lot of space.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you need counts of the movies in common  as well as the total movies both actors have acted in, you can try something like this

```
MATCH (a:Actor{name:"Alec Guinness"})-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(b:Person{name:"Harrison Ford"}) 
WITH a,b,count(m) as common,
size(a-[:ACTED_IN]->()) as totalA,
size(b-[:ACTED_IN]->()) as totalB 
MERGE (a)-[:SAME_MOVIE {weight: formula}]-(b)
```

Replace `formula` with your calculation using `common`,`totalA`, `totalB`

Make sure you have an index on the `name` property of the `Actor` label.

**UPDATE**

Instead of creating the relationship, calculate what you require and sort it before returning/further matching

```
MATCH (a:Actor)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(b:Person) 
WITH a,b,count(m) as common,
size(a-[:ACTED_IN]->()) as totalA,
size(b-[:ACTED_IN]->()) as totalB 
WITH a,b,<formula using common,totalA,totalB> as weight
ORDER BY weight
RETURN a,b
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Luanne. It is getting close to what I want. In this case, I do not want to create a physical relationship using merge, instead I would like to create this relationship on the fly for sorting purpose and to reduce physical size. Is it possible to use RETURN instead of merge? Also, my formula is simply common/totalA, but it seems like the data stored in a relationship is simply 0 value (should be decimal). Kindly advise.

Comment: Hope I've understood you correctly- you can just use the calculations to order by and then either return the actors, or perform further matches. See updated answer

Comment: This is exactly what I need. I have put toFloat function on the division and get a correct number. I will mark your answer as the correct one.Thanks a lot!!

Comment: No problem. You might want to consider really creating these relationships if you're going to calculate this over and over at run time. Space shouldn't be a concern. To keep the weights updated, you could always trigger a recalculation for the actor/movie updated.

Comment: In fact I am considering this at the beginning. But look at my data which has 1 million nodes and I am trying to connect all of those nodes, the calculator just give me an incredibly scary HD size. However, I will try the performance for those and see what can I do.